# Mongodb collection mapping c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, collections, configuration, mapping

I have used NHibernate to develop applications previously, so this will be my first time developing using mongodb and the c# driver.

In NHibernate it is possible to setup a configuration file to map the classes to tables. Doing this allowed me to map different concrete classes to different tables.

It was then possible to use the same c# code with a different configuration file in another application. Having specified a different  mapping the objects would then be written and retrieved from different tables.

All the polymorphic mapping was isolated to the configuration thus a database management class could take an interface as a parameter (removing the burden from me to manage the INSERT commands)

With Mongodb I am struggling to find a similar solution. Most of the examples use hard coded names to retrieve the collection to allow read/ write.

Is there a solution within the mongodb c# driver that would allow me to isolate the mapping from the code ?

If I can not do the above are the some attributes I could placed in the concrete classes to divert the reading and writting to a different collection

Note: I need to avoid writting all the data in one collection

Comment: why do you need to avoid to write data of the same objecttype to the same collection? To me this seems more like a designissue.

Comment: As I extend my classes during development, I would prefer to keep the data isolated.   Additional applications will only focus on a subsection of the classes therefore I do not want them access a collection that has everything. Data that a new application would have no interest in using

Comment: you have two options: create a different object with a reference (ID, whatever) or save it all in one collection